# Transform an if.. elseif chain of distinct conditions into case switch

Tags: php, if-statement, switch-statement

Simple curiosity, is there any way to convert what this following into a switch loop?

**PHP :**

```
if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    $error = array('type' => 'error', 'value' => 'email');
}
elseif (!preg_match($regex_name, $username)) {
    $error = array('type' => 'error', 'value' => 'username');
}
elseif (!preg_match($regex_name, $firstname) && preg_match($regex_name, $lastname)) {
    $error = array('type' => 'error', 'value' => 'name');
}
elseif ($password !== $password_conf) {
    $error = array('type' => 'error', 'value' => 'password');
}
elseif (checkdate($birthday_d, $birthday_m, $birthday_y) == false) {
    $error = array('type' => 'error', 'value' => 'date');
}
else {
    $error = array('type' => 'success');
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: there probably would be with a `switch(true)`, but I doubt it'd be cleaner

Comment: Why do you want to change this to switch case ?

Comment: It is doable but it will be very ugly - it will nested switch at every new conditional statement

Comment: That's a good question... to the best of my knowledge, no there isn't a better cleaner way. you did good

Comment: What is a "switch-loop"..?

Comment: Btw. this code could be made "cleaner" if you write everything in oop-style, but doing this wouldn't end in many classes and would be in no case shorter than your solution

Comment: Okay all, that was just to know, I don't really wanna change that, just for my knowledges! :) Thank you.

Comment: This doesn't mean the code cannot be improved. I especially don't like the way you report errors, or the absence of one. What is a succesful error?

Comment: I use them in ajax. 'success' means here that all conditions have been succesfully executed and I'm playing back with ajax. Each his method, I learned like this.

Comment: No reason or benefit to making this a switch, but I recommend making them distinct IF statements and building up an array of all errors. Any combination or all of these errors could be present, but you're only going to report the first problem. I recommend a status variable to indicate whether or not there were errors, then an array of the errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just for completeness an example of what a transformation to a switch would look like:

```
switch(true) {
    case (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)):
          $error = array('type' => 'error', 'value' => 'email');
          break;
    case (!preg_match($regex_name, $username)):
          $error = array('type' => 'error', 'value' => 'username');
          break;
    //...   
}
```

In the end this is just a complicated way to say `if this is true`.